# What's a good Search Engine for Searching for Programming Tutorials, Code Examples, News and other Programming Related things?

Tags: search, search-engine

Yes, there's google.com. But I wonder if programmers use anything else for searching on the web related to programming.

Comment: Any specific language? You could always try http://stackoverflow.com :)

Comment: nope. Google still works, most of the time it points you towards SO... but what you might be looking for seems like an aggregator.

Comment: No specific programming language. Any programming language on the web.

Answer (score 2):

You can use code search engines, e.g. [koders](http://www.koders.com/)

Comment: Google link is broken

Comment: Google code search was shut down by Google. Related question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7778034/replacement-for-google-code-search